# Changing linear programming form in Megiddo algorithm

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

In Megiddo linear programming algorithm in 2 dimensions we need to reformulate task from

\begin{array}{l}
\operatorname{minimize}_{x_1, x_2}& c_1x_1+c_2x_2\\
s.t&a_{i1}x_1+a_{i1}x_2 \ge \beta_i\quad(i=1,\dots, n).
\end{array}

into

\begin{array}{l}
\operatorname{minimize}_{x, y} & y\\
s.t&y \ge a_ix+b_i&\quad (i\in I_1),\\
&y \le a_ix+b_i&\quad (i\in I_2),\\
&a\le x \le b
\end{array}

Here i don't understand from where $a, b$ come in the last line?

[Source](http://inrg.csie.ntu.edu.tw/algorithm2014/homework/P&S%20Megiddo-83.pdf) see 2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the transformation the author is doing is to rotate the LP so that the objective vector $c$ points straight down (*i.e.* has zero $x$ coefficient), like so:

[image: rotation01]

When they do this, the coefficient of the $y$ variable is either $0$, or it is non-zero, in which case it can be scaled to equal 1. Here's an illustration of when they equal zero (and hence in which $a$ and $b$ are finite):

[image: rotation02]

However, as the paper notes, we could have $a$ and $b$ equal to $\infty$, as illustrated here (the cone is supposed to be infinite):

[image: rotation03]

Basically, the $a$ and $b$ just account for when the rotated LP has a constraint with zero coefficient on the $y$ variable.